$X_n \rightarrow_d X$ and UI implies $\mathbb{E}X_n\rightarrow\mathbb{E} X$

Claim: Let $(X_i),X$ be real valued r.v.s. Then $X_n \rightarrow_d X$ and uniformly integrable implies $\mathbb{E}X_n\rightarrow\mathbb{E} X$

How can I prove this claim directly?
Here's how I proved it using machinery: If $X_n\rightarrow_d X$ then there exists a sequence $(\overline{X_n})$ and r.v. $\overline{X}$ with the same distributions as $(X_n)$ and $X$ resp. on the same probability space such that $\overline{X}_n\rightarrow_{p}\overline{X}$. The new sequence is also UI, so we have $\overline{X}_n \rightarrow_{L^1} \overline{X}$. Thus $\mathbb{E}\overline{X}_n\rightarrow \mathbb{E}\overline{X}$ and we can remove the overlines as the distributions are the same.

Let $\Phi_R$ be the map defined as $$
\varphi_R(x)=\begin{cases}
-R&\mbox{ if }x\leqslant -R,\\
x&\mbox{ if }-R<x\leqslant R,\\
R&\mbox{ if }x>R. 
\end{cases}$$
The convergence in distribution implies that for each fixed $R$, $\mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X_n)\right]\to \mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X)\right]$. Writing
$$
\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[X_n\right]-\mathbb E\left[X\right]\right\rvert\leqslant \left\lvert \mathbb E\left[X_n\right]-\mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X_n)\right]\right\rvert+\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[\Phi_R\left(X_n\right)\right]-\mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X)\right]\right\rvert+\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X)\right]-\mathbb E\left[X\right]\right\rvert,
$$
we derive that for each fixed $R$,
$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[X_n\right]-\mathbb E\left[X\right]\right\rvert\leqslant \sup_{n\geqslant 1} \left\lvert \mathbb E\left[X_n\right]-\mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X_n)\right]\right\rvert+\left\lvert \mathbb E\left[\Phi_R(X)\right]-\mathbb E\left[X\right]\right\rvert.
$$

" The convergence in distribution implies that for each fixed ..." Are you using the fact that $\mathbb{E}(f(X_n)) \rightarrow \mathbb{E}(f(X))$ for every $f$ bounded and continuous?

Yes, I am starting from this definition of convergence in distribution.
